# How to change subtitle user's home directory?

Tags: command-line, users, su

I added a user (user2) in a WSL2 environment and then wanna change that user2's home directory to a different directory.
But something must be wrong.

```
$ usermod -d /var/lib/app1 user2
usermod: no changes
```

```
$ vim /etc/passwd
user2:x:1001:1001::/var/lib/app1:/bin/sh
```

```
$ sudo su user2
```

It wasn't `/var/lib/app1` but `/home/abc`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: @Kulfy Sorry. I am not familliar about linux(ubuntu), so I cannot understand 'the owner of /var/lib/app1'.
Could you tell me about it easily?
default user and subtitle user are both me.
I wrote that subtitle user is 'user2', but exactly 'airflow'
For airflow application, I add subtitle user 'airflow' and 'airflow initdb' in /var/lib/airflow.

Comment: Do you mean when you run `sudo su user2`  you're still in user1's home, i.e., prompt is like `user2@host:/home/user1`?

Comment: @Kulfy Yes! ```sudo su user2; pwd``` then /home/user1.

Comment: Did my answer answered your question? Also, I see that you changed "substitute user" to "subtitle user". What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Kulfy Yes. With your efforts, I was able to solve the problem I was having. Thank you.
Because I noticed that 'su' is 'subtitle user' late, So I changed "substitute user" to "subtitle user" in title.

Comment: Where did you read `su` is "subtitle" user? According to [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) as well as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Su_(Unix)), it stands for "substitute user".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the intended behavior. `su` by default doesn't change working directory. It only switches user. According to [`su` manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html):

> For backward compatibility, `su` defaults to not change the current directory and to only set the environment variables `HOME` and `SHELL` (plus `USER` and `LOGNAME` if the target *user* is not root).

`su` does change user and `$HOME` but it doesn't `cd` to that user's `$HOME`.

For example, I have 2 users, `kulfy` and `kulfy1`. BASH is the default shell of the earlier one and sh (which is a symlink to DASH) of the later one.

```bsh
kulfy@leo:~$ echo $HOME
/home/kulfy
kulfy@leo:~$ sudo su kulfy1
$ echo $USER  
kulfy1  # User changed
$ pwd      
/home/kulfy # but directory didn't change 
$ echo $HOME
/home/kulfy1 # and HOME variable now points to the HOME of user2, i.e., kulfy1
```

To change the directory as well, you can use `--login` or simply `-` with `su`. From the manpage:

> **`-`**, **`-l`**, **`--login`**
>         Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar to a real login:
>
> o    clears all the environment variables except **`TERM`** and variables specified by **`--whitelist-environment`**
>
> o    initializes the environment variables **`HOME`**, **`SHELL`**, **`USER`**, **`LOGNAME`**, and **`PATH`**
>
> o    changes to the target user's home directory
>
> o    sets argv[0] of the shell to '-' in order to make the shell a login shell

```bsh
kulfy@leo:~$ sudo su --login kulfy1 
$ echo $USER
kulfy1
$ pwd
/home/kulfy1  # directory changed automatically
$ echo $HOME
/home/kulfy1
```